# apt-get command not found in Vagrant/Window

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

When I run `vagran up` command, I get the error `apt-get` command not found in `vagrant`, my pc is using window-10.

Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # VM Box
  config.vm.box = "centos-7"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.100"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = 2048
    vb.cpus = 4
  end
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "bootstrap.sh"
end
```

bootstrap.sh

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get apgrate
sudo apt-get install -y git
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're using a centos box

```
config.vm.box = "centos-7"
```

so you should use the [`yum`](https://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum) package manager, `apt` is used for ubuntu family and is not compatible with the other os family (Debian vs Fedora)

To install git on centos replace your bootstrap script by

```
yum update
yum install -y git
```

Comment: Henri, thank. Now, I decided to use `docker`. Vagrant `shell` have to modify base of vm box.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `yum` and trying `$ vagrant box update`? Also, you can get more in depth logs by using `$ vagrant up --debug` or if you would like to save it to a file `$ vagrant up --debug &> vagrant.log`. I always recommend doing some VM house keeping as well by making sure all VMs are stopped then run `$ vagrant reload --provision` on the VM having the issues. As always, the best part of using Vagrant is the ability to wipe it and start over again.